# SQL query to find a class that contains minimum price

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains different flight class names along with prices. Now my query result shows all of the results, flight names with corresponding classes and corresponding prices. Here is the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT f.dCity, f.aCity, f.date, f.flight_code, f.route, f.timeLeaving, f.timeLanding, f.price, f.class, i.airline_name , 
            (SELECT location FROM iataairportcodes where iata_code='$fromm') as dLocation,
            (SELECT airport_name FROM iataairportcodes where iata_code='$fromm') as dAirport,
            (SELECT location FROM iataairportcodes where iata_code='$too') as aLocation,
            (SELECT airport_name FROM iataairportcodes where iata_code='$too') as aAirport
            FROM flights_test AS f, iataairlinescodes AS i
            WHERE f.airline_code = i.iata_code
            AND f.dCity = '$fromm'
            AND f.aCity = '$too' 
            AND f.date='$newDate'";
```

But I want to find and display only that class, which contains minimum price; i.e., all data of that class only which contains minimum price.
(Forget about php variables please, those are from other sources)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: It's mysql @danielsepulvedab

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query